# Are these sequences total sequences?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, orthogonality

***DEFINITIONS/CONCEPTS THAT I USE***

- When I refer to $\mathbb{K}$ (field), I am only referring to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.
- I am using, for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $a<b$, $C[a,b]=\{f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{K}\space\space |\space\space f  \textrm{ is continuous} \}$ with a dot product $<\cdot,\cdot>$ defined for $f,g\in C[a,b]$ as:
  $$ 
  <f,g>=\int_{a}^{b} f(t)\overline{g(t)} dt
  $$
  i.e, $(C[a,b],<\cdot,\cdot>)$ is a preHilbert space.
- A sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ in a preHilbert space is called **total** if $x$ is orthogonal to $x_{n}$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, only in the case that $x=0$.

Now, let's start with the exercise; I will list the questions and then give my attempt below.
I am asked to prove the following:

> In $C[-1,1]$,  $(1,t,t^2,t^3,...)$ (here I am working with $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$) is a total sequence:

Let's just take the definition; take $z=z(t)\in C[-1,1]$ such that $z\perp t^{n}$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$; i.e, $\int_{-1}^{1} z(t)t^{n} dt=0$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. With this last thing, I must conclude that $z(t)=0$, $\forall t\in [-1,1]$... And being honest, I am lost.

> In $C[-\pi,\pi]$,  $(1,\sin(t),\cos(t),\sin(2t),\cos(2t),...)$ (here I am working with $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$) is a total sequence:

(I am also lost here)

> In $C[-\pi,\pi]$,  $(e^{int})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ (here I am working with $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$) is a total sequence:

Here, following similar arguments, I will need to prove that if there is $z=z(t)\in C[-\pi,\pi]$ such that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} z(t)\overline{e^{int}} dt=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} z(t)e^{-int} dt=0$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $z(t)=0$, $\forall t\in [-\pi,\pi]$; in this case, I will have to take into account that if $\tilde{z}\in C[-\pi,\pi]$ has not null imaginary part, $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \tilde{z}(t) dt = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} Re\tilde{z}(t) dt + i\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} Im\tilde{z}(t) dt$, but I am also lost...

I would really appreciate some hint/help on it... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint for the first one.  Prove in steps: (a) $\int_{-1}^{1} z(t)t^{n} dt=0$ for $n \in \mathbb N$.  (b) $\int_{-1}^{1} z(t) p(t) dt=0$ for all polynomrials $p$.  (c) $\int_{-1}^{1} z(t) f(t) dt=0$ for all continuous functions $f$. (d) $z(t) = 0$

Comment: Thanks for answering @GEdgar ! So, let me try: any $p(t)$ could be expressed as a linear combination of elements of the sequence, so, as integral is linear, and using (a) that comes from hypothesis, I will have (b). For (c), I'm not sure what we can use... Taylor probably? I'm not sure if it is 'legal' to 'interchange' the integral with an infinite sum... And with (c) I am quite sure that (d) follows trivial (anyways, could you give me a line or two formalising (c)$\Rightarrow$ (d)?). Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key result you are missing is the [Stone Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem,_complex_version).

---

$\boxed{1}$ Assume that $$\int_{-1}^1 z(t) t^n dt = 0.$$
Then, by linearity of the integral
$$\int_{-1}^1 z(t)p(t) dt = 0$$
for all polynomial functions $p: [-1,1]\to \mathbb{C}$. By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, these functions are uniformly dense in $[-1,1]$, so there is a sequence of polynomial functions $\{p_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that
$$ p_n \to \overline{z}$$
where the convergence is uniform. Hence, since we can switch an integral and a uniform limit, we get
$$\int_{-1}^1 |z(t)|^2 dt = \int_{-1}^1 z(t)\overline{z}(t) dt = \lim_n \int_{-1}^1 z(t)p_n(t)dt = 0$$
from which it follows that $z=0$.

---

$\boxed{2}$ I leave this as an exercise for you after you understand the third subquestion, which I will now explain.

---

$\boxed{3}$ Proceed as follows:

(1) Use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem to prove that the span of $\{e^{int}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is uniformly dense in $C([-\pi, \pi])$. It may be useful to note that the relations
$$e^{int}e^{imt}= e^{i(m+n)t}, \quad \overline{e^{int}}= e^{-int}$$
hold.

(2) Proceed as in exercise $\boxed{1}$.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the feedback! @QuantumSpace So, for $\boxed{\mathbf{3}}$, we must have to prove that $\{e^{int}\}_{n\in\mathbf{Z}}$ is a separating subset; this is, if I take $t_{1},t_{2} \in[-\pi,\pi]$ such that $t_{1}\neq t_{2}$, I will be able to find $e^{int}\in\{e^{int}\}_{n\in\mathbf{Z}}$ such that $e^{int_{1}}\neq e^{int_{2}}$; it is sufficient to take any of those functions (distinct from 1) as they are all one to one (excepting the constantly equal to one). With this, I am able to apply the theorem, so those functions are uniformly dense in $[-\pi,\pi]$ and... (same as in (1)).

Comment: @rubiksman23 This sounds about right, but the functions itself are not dense, but their linear span is.

Comment: Oh true! sorry, I am not familiar with this theorem at all... So, as the linear span is dense in $C[-\pi,\pi]$, there is a sequence in that family converging to any function chosen (in $C[-\pi,\pi]$), and so, then, I can proceed as in the first case (with the conjugate and all of that)...

Comment: @rubikman23 Yes, that's it. I don't think there is a (fast) way to do it without the Stone-Weierstrass theorem though.

Comment: Thank you so much for introducing me to this theorem!

Comment: @rubikman23 You are welcome! It is a very useful theorem that should be in the toolbox of every (functional) analysist!